# Using Groovy markupbuilder to build simple web page. No such DSL method 'body' found among steps

Tags: jenkins-groovy, markupbuilder

I am trying to build a simple webpage using HTML markup but I get the error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'body' found among steps

Code:

```
@NonCPS
def parseJsonForXml(inputJson) {
try {
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    def markup = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
    markup.html {
        body {
            div {
                h1 "Test Page"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know what effect `@NonCPS` is having but without that, the code you show there seems to work fine.  Is this happening in a Jenkins context?

Comment: Yea, this is happening within Jenkins. I will try removing the @NonCPS

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/a82dabc95f13cafa2581088b831d21a6

Comment: Yea, thats weird. Im still getting the same issue after removing @NonCPS

Comment: NonCPS tells Jenkins not to apply CPS transformations, more about them - https://github.com/cloudbees/groovy-cps/
In this context, it's better not to apply CPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins does lots of Groovy magic like CPS transformation, custom method interceptots, etc.
In short, the nested closers are not called on the markup object as they are supposed to be in groovy, instead Jenkins changes the receiver object and calls them on the main script, so it checks if the body DSL step is defined in an internal map of all DSL method defined in Jenkins and plugin.
To make it work change make the caller object explicit

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

@NonCPS
def parseJsonForXml() {
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    def markup = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
    markup.with {
        html {
            body {
                div {
                    h1 "Test Page"
                }
            }
        }    
    }
    
    return writer.toString()
}
println(parseJsonForXml())
```

It does exactly what you expect it to do

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] echo
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>Test Page</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you!